# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_32 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 256]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am building a Conv1D model with train data (28659, 257) and test data (5053, 257), but I am facing a value error that says: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 256]

## size of datasets

```
print(train_data.shape)
print(test_data.shape)
```

## model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', input_shape=(256,1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(loss='CategoricalCrossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_data.values[:, 0:256], to_categorical(train_data.values[:, 256]), epochs=180, batch_size=500)
y_pred = model.predict(test_data.values[:, 0:256])
```

## testing accuracy

```
y_pred = model.predict(test_data.values[:,0:256])
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)
accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(to_categorical(test_data.values[:,256]),y_pred)
print(f'Testing accuracy of the model is {accuracy*100:.4f}%')
```

The error is from the fit(), but I cannot figure my mistake with the calculation! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

try to reshape your train and test data :

```
X_train=np.reshape(train_data,(train_data.shape[0], train_data.shape[1],1))
X_test=np.reshape(test_data,(test_data.shape[0], test_data.shape[1],1))
```

You can't feed values like : `[1,2,3,4]`, you have to feed your values like `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]`

Comment: when I did that, I got this error ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(28659, 257, 1)

Comment: you feed 257 into a 256 input (first convolutionnal layer)

Comment: I did not understand that, but I still tried doing that, facing the same error.